# how to make PKG_CHECK_MODULES work with static libraries?

Tags: static-libraries, autoconf, pkg-config

I have in configure.ac:

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([LIBXML2], [libxml-2.0 >= 2.6.26])
```

and I use `$(LIBXML2_LIBS)` in Makefile.am.

It works if libxml2 is linked dynamically, but now if it's static linking fails because of missing `-lz`.

A workaround for the user is to set

```
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config --static"
```

but I'd rather enhance the configure script in such a way that this workaround is not necessary.

Of course I don't know if libxml2 will be static or DSO, so I can't just hardcode the `--static` flag. Anyone has a macro for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update - the [last comment](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19541#c7) in the above bug report shows that they addressed the problem by adding a new macro, `PKG_CHECK_MODULES_STATIC`. See also [this commit](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pkg-config/pkg-config/commit/0efb668bd5990f52a6a93b2cde037185edbe11b0).

This [appears to be live](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pkg-config/pkg-config/blob/master/pkg.m4.in#L195) in pkg-config versions > 0.29.

Answer (score 1):

Using:

```
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config --static"
```

seems to be the way to do it according to [this pkg-config bug report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=19541).

Comment: This is workaround for the user mentioned in the question, not a fix for conifgure.ac.

Comment: Unfortunately, the fix for configure.ac seems to be (in Comment 3 of the bug report) "There doesn't seem to be a good solution".